# Why can't the problem of constancy be solved?

Tags: parametric-functions

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := a E^x - Log[x]
ForAll[x, 1 < x < 2, f'[x] > 0]
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

Why can't the problem of constancy be solved?

Comment: @csn899 `a>Exp[-x]/x`

Comment: The final result maybe `a>=1/E`. I don't know how to only use Mathematica to deduce this, so I am not the down vote.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  The final result does not depend on `x`.

Comment: Mathematica cannot easily solve many mathematical problems

Comment: @csn899 And it can also solve many as well!

Comment: @cvgmt That is already clear: `a > ArgMin[Exp[-x]/x, 1 < x < 2, x]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Should be `a >= MaxValue[Exp[-x]/x, 1 <= x <= 2, x]`.

Comment: @cvgmt Correct, thans for your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
cond = Reduce[f'[x] > 0 && 1 < x < 2, Reals]
(*1 < x < 2 && a > E^-x/x*)

Maximize[{cond[[2, 2]], 1 < x < 2}, x]
(* {1/E, {x -> 1.}} *)
```

result: `a>1/E==0.367879`

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to use Mathematica to deal with the original question. Here we only use Mathematica to prove that `a==1/E` is actually one cases.

```
f[x_] = a E^x - Log[x];
Resolve[Implies[a == 1/E, ForAll[x, 1 < x < 2, f'[x] > 0]], Reals]
Reduce[Implies[a == 1/E, ForAll[x, 1 < x < 2, f'[x] > 0]], Reals]
Reduce[Block[{a = 1/E}, ForAll[x, 1 < x < 2, f'[x] > 0]]]
```

> `True`.
> `True`.
> `True`.

Answer (score 0):

````
In[1063]:= Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := a E^x - Log[x]
f'[x] > 0 /. k_.*E^x - 1/x > 0 :> k > 1/(x E^x)

Out[1065]= a > E^-x/x

In[1083]:= g[x_] = E^-x/x
{Reduce[{g'[x] > 0, 1 < x < 2}, x], 
 Reduce[{g'[x] < 0, 1 < x < 2}, x]}
a > g[1]

Out[1083]= E^-x/x

Out[1084]= {False, 1 < x < 2}

Out[1085]= a > 1/E
```
````